# Exclude a Value from results in XML data

Tags: php, logic, iteration

I have an XML feed which I am retrieving data from.

I currently have the code written to display the values, I would like to find a specific value and remove it from the display.

XML Code is below

```
<Agents>
   <Agent>
      <id></id>
      <description></description>
      <name></name>
   </Agent>
</Agents>
```

Current PHP to find the value based on the ID is below.

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "xml feed";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$idToFind = 1922;
for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {
    $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
    if ($id != $idToFind)
        continue;
      {

    $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
    $name = $xml->Agent[$i]->name;

    $html .= "<h2>$name</h2><h3>$id</h3>";}

echo $html;
?>
```

So this finds the ID 1922 and displays it, but instead I want to find the ID 1922 and exclude it but still show the other 299 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read it correctly all it takes is change your if statement from:

```
if ($id != $idToFind)
```

to

```
if ($id == $idToFind)
```

that way you revert the condition and you'll get all the nodes except for the one with ID 1922.